# Why the values are not stored properly in pointers when assigning values at runtime(using scanf) in C language?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

In C, When i assign values to pointers during compile time and print values, they are printing correct.

```
int main(void) {
    int b;
    int* a=&b;
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        *a=i;
        a++;
    }

    a=&b;
    for(int  i=0;i<=5;i++){
        printf("%d ", *(a+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i am getting output as: 0 1 2 3 4 5

But when i assign values during runtime(using scanf) and print values, only the second value in pointer is replaced by last value of the pointer.

```
int main(void) {
    int b;
    int* a=&b;
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        int t;
        scanf("%d", &t);
        *a=t;
        a++;
    }
    a=&b;
    for(int  i=0;i<=5;i++){
        printf("%d ", *(a+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input: 0 1 2 3 4 5
Output: 0 5 2 3 4 5

However whatever the size of pointer, only second element is getting replaced by the last element in the pointer.
Can anyone clarify this.

Comment: The both programs have undefined behaviot because you are trying to write in the memory beyond the memory occupied by the variable b.

Comment: Ask yourself: If you could do this, why'd we need arrays?

Comment: @SouravGhosh For example we would need arrays for multidimensional arrays.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why not do the trick twice? ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior. You're accessing `a[0]` to `a[5]`, that's space for `6` integers. However, you only have space for one integer:

```
int b; // your one integer
int* a=&b;
```

If you increase `a`, it won't point to valid memory anymore. Instead of just having one `int`, try an array of `6` `int` instead:

```
int b[6];
int* a = b; // you can drop the "&" now as arrays decay to their pointers anyway
```

You might ask yourself "why did it work the first time and not the second time if its undefined behavior both times?". The problem with undefined behavior is that it is not guaranteed to do anything in particular. Working sometimes and the not working at other times is a common manifestation of UB. It could give you the result you expect and seem to work, and then suddenly fail when you try to demonstrate your program to a client.

---

On a side note, may I interest you in accessing arrays using this better readable syntax instead?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
}
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: One consequence of Murphy's Law is that code with undefined behaviour can be expected to pass all your test cases, and then fail when delivered to a client.     While this is not a guaranteed consequence of undefined behaviour, I point out that Murphy is considered an optimist.